# Can not configure multistore option

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I dont really understand multistore setup and need some help:

1. I enabled multistore option in prestashop 1.7.
2. I created second shop in admin multistore panel.
3. Now  my question is should i  install fresh prestashop installation in some subdirectory and point
   physical uri of the second shop created in point 2 and this will works or prestashop uses the same instance as second shop but then why there is physical uri to second shop will presta create it automatically in pointed directory?

i want to have different domains multistore

Answer (score 0):

Multistore works with a single Prestashop installation / database.

Make sure to configure the shop URLs / URI properly after activating the feature.

If you setup the second store URL to use a subfolder, everything will be handled by Prestashop **.htaccess** file.

If you setup the second store to be in a subdomain / other domain, you have to configure your webserver so that the **document root** of the second domain is the same of the main domain - Then Prestashop will handle this accordingly.

Comment: so i dont need to change the physical uri which is needed while creating second store in multistore options or should it be the same as the first shop?

Comment: if your shop domains are *not* into subfolders (ie. mydomain.com/shop) , it is fine to leave the physical URL to "/" for both shops.